# Android: Android Studio emulator executes code fine, but real life application on phone causes onChangedListener to not run

Tags: android, android-studio, textwatcher

The purpose of this app is to hide a secret message inside an edittext and to display the message when the user presses a button. The problem I have is that to iniate the secret message, the user needs to start typing and then use a period to start the process. On the period press and until the user presses a comma, any key thats pressed that would appear on the edittext will get replaced and have a char from a pre-determined string put in.

The problem that shows up on my Nexus 5 with at least Android 4.4, is that when the user presses period, it doesnt replace the period.

The code works perfectly from within the android studio emulator. The real methods that I feel like that aren't working properly is the onTextChanged method or the onKeyUp method. I'm not sure what to do here. I've written a lot of code that always works on the emulator and translates to equivilent success on real devices. What do?

the code is on a pastebin: **http://pastebin.com/iupRJpZi**

Comment: Is onKeyUp supposed to be called for the soft keyboard, or only guaranteed for hardware keyboards? Also, there's this from the `Activity#onKeyUp` docs: "Called when a key was released and not handled by any of the views inside of the activity. So, for example, key presses while the cursor is inside a TextView will not trigger the event (unless it is a navigation to another object) because TextView handles its own key presses." Based on this, maybe an actual touch on an `EditText` does not trigger onKeyUp because the `EditText` itself handles the event?

Comment: Im pretty sure I'm aiming for the soft keyboards as the modern android devices don't have a physical keyboard in place. Stkent, I'm not sure what youre suggesting here. Should I get rid of the onKeyUp and use a onTouch method instead? It would probally drastically affect the code.

Comment: onKeyUp won't necessarily be called for a softkeyboard.  Its only likely to happen if the keyboard is in dumb mode, and may not even then.  Generally soft keyboards use commitText which does NOT generate key events

Comment: @Jayizzle if you want to read events from a soft keyboard, use a TextChangedWatcher.

Comment: I use both onkeyup and textchangedwatcher. I guess i need to drop the onkeyup method now.